# Load timeout for modules while including a module with dependency

Tags: requirejs

I am getting an error:
"Error: Load timeout for modules"

While trying to include a module with dependencies.

Am I doing this incorrectly?

My bootstrap:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "js",
    paths: {
        JqueryUiLatest: "jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom",
    }
});
require([
    'modules/outlookPopupModule'
], function(OutlookPopupModule){

    ...

});
```

My module:

```
define([
        'jquery',
        "JqueryUiLatest"

    ], function ($, JqueryUI) {
```

it seems to work if I replace "JqueryUiLatest" with the actual file "jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom" in the module, but this seems to defeat the purpose of being able to use the config.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here?

Comment: In which folder is the module, relative to baseUrl?

Comment: Did you create a path config option for `jquery`? It's necessary to use it as an AMD module. You should also shim jQuery UI to be aware it needs jQuery as a dependency.

Comment: @PaulGrime it's in modules/

Answer (score 0):

By my experience requirejs often fails with timeout when shim dependency module is a plain JS script, not wrapped AMD module. The only solution I have now - load such files manually prior to requirejs or load them explicitly in require/define calls by full name (including .js extensions). In require/define no timeout occurs.